# Angular2 directive for disabling all buttons and inputs on page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I want to write a attribute directive, which applied to element will disable all inputs and buttons inside it, so the form will become read-only. My present solutions looks like this (only for buttons, but its straightforward for anchors and inputs):

```
@Directive(
    {
        selector: '[read-only]'
    }
)
export class ReadOnlyDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    private currentElement: ElementRef;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        this.currentElement = element;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        let elements = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('button');
        let elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
        elementsArray.forEach(element => this.renderer.setElementAttribute(element, 'disabled', 'disabled'));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use plain javascript for finding elements, but renderer for setting their attribute.

I've got two questions:

1. Is there a better, cleaner Angular2-way to do this without finding elements with plain javascript?
2. Is there any way to make this secure in front end, to be sure that user don't make the button enabled and click it? I thought about structural directive that will remove buttons and place dummy there, but I don't know what is the correct approach.

Comment: "Is there any way to make this secure in front end..." Never assume the front end can be 100% secure.

Comment: @Phix of course there will be also backend validation, but I meant best possible option.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar scenario. At the end did you follow the pattern proposed in the question?

Comment: Hello @gipinani - yes, we are using this directive in our application and it's working as it should.